# What's diverge in lisp

Tags: lisp, conditional-statements, conditional-expressions

for example,

> (cond ((< 2 1) 2 )((< 1 2 ) 1))
>    has value 1. OK;

But, I saw that `(cond (diverge 1) (ture 0))` is undefined, if diverge does not terminate' in my major book.

What's the diverge in lisp??

I don't know that.

Also, I don't know exactly what is side effects in lisp.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming the code you originally meant is

```
(cond ((diverge 1) (ture 0)))
```

then the result of that expression is undefined (or better, diverging, too) when we assume `diverge` to be an - as its name suggests - diverging operation.

A [diverging operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_(computer_science)) is one that does not converge to a result, like for example an infinite loop.

There's no `diverge` defined in the Common Lisp standard (what practical purpose would it have?), so your book is just omitting the "implementation details" of an diverging computation by wrapping it in a operation and naming it appropriately.

Note that the original code can expose the same behaviour if one assumes `diverge` to be a symbol macro.

Comment: OP's code could be valid and never terminates, provided there is something like `(define-symbol-macro diverge (loop))` elsewhere ;-)

Comment: Ah yes, symbol macros. I wanted to keep the complexity low, but added a note :)

Answer (score 2):

As shown, `diverge` and `ture` would name variables that are evaluated as booleans.  The value of the entire expression is 1 if `diverge` is true, 0 if `ture` is true, and `nil` if neither is true.

Since you did not show the context, especially how `diverge` and `ture` are bound, more cannot be said about your snippet.

Maybe you meant something like `(cond ((diverge 1) (ture 0)))`.  Then `diverge` would be an operator.  It is not defined in the Common Lisp standard, so it most likely comes from somewhere else in your book.